# Installing wireless drivers in Arch Linux?

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, installation, arch-linux

I am totally new to the Arch Linux. I want to install wireless drivers for my PC and need your help. My PC is Dell Studio 1555. I ran the below command for my wireless card info:

```
lspci -nn -d 14e4: 

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Limited NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1698] (rev 10)
```

Also, below command:

```
dmesg | grep firmware

[    9.948036] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode16_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[    9.948047] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode16_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[    9.948061] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode16_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[    9.948071] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode16_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[    9.948440] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
```

Note: I can connect via wired.

Comment: Well, you clearly need the firmware. However, it’s proprietary. See the [Arch wiki page on Broadcom](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/broadcom_wireless) for more information.

Comment: The page is not clear, what are the commands?

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, you can go to  http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware (not specific to Arch Linux).
Then you can follow the link to http://linuxwireless.sipsolutions.net/en/users/Drivers/b43/ and, as suggested there, download and build a tarball. Type in these commands on the CL:

```
wget http://bues.ch/b43/fwcutter/b43-fwcutter-018.tar.bz2 http://bues.ch/b43/fwcutter/b43-fwcutter-018.tar.bz2.asc
gpg --verify b43-fwcutter-018.tar.bz2.asc
tar xjf b43-fwcutter-018.tar.bz2
cd b43-fwcutter-018
make
sudo make install
cd ..
```

This worked for me having exactly the same wireless chip as you.

You might also be interested in this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/584018/659729) (specific to Arch Linux), which details the above comment to your question (especially for B43 drivers).