# How to manually create a wireless interface for an Arch Linux computer?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, arch-linux

I have recently installed Arch Linux for the first time, and I am having extreme difficulty setting up my Wi-Fi.

The physical hardware and drivers are there, and listed by the computer via `lspci -k`:

```
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: ssb
```

And this is the output `ip link`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:e8:9f:a2:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
00:00.0
```

See the problem? There is a device, and drivers, but no `wlan0` interface.

Now, I have read a few articles about it, but none had circumstances like mine.

What is the recommended way to do this (I have `wifi-menu` installed, but it is having issues)?

Are there files I can create, or will I need to do something more along the lines of

```
ip address add
```

Edit: In response to some comments, I have checked extensively to make sure my drivers are correct and up to date. I am pretty sure I need to somehow generate an interface for the device, or something to that effect.

Comment: The driver is probably not correct for that chip.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing wireless Broadcom drivers on Arch Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/583712/installing-wireless-broadcom-drivers-on-arch-linux)

Comment: Check that you have [the `b43` drivers installed](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless#b43).

Comment: You are only looking at post-initialization information.  Instead you need to check the system log (i.e. the `dmesg` command) for driver initialization status and error messages.  A firmware load failure is a common reason for wifi unavailability.

Comment: That may be the case. I checked `dmesg`, and it seems I have three b43-related error messages. Thank you for your help.